# Return the lower of two dates or specific text if both are null

Tags: sql-server, date, reporting-services, case

Im trying to find the lower date from two fields. The field could also be NULL so choose the non NULL or if both NULL then 'Some Error'

POdate is populated from this (im putting this in a temp table along with the other fields)

```
    (SELECT MIN(PD.ReceiptDate)
FROM Structure.Parts
INNER JOIN Purchase.PurchaseOrderDetails PD   ON pd.PartID = structure.Parts.PartID    
INNER JOIN Purchase.PurchaseOrders PO     
ON PD.PurchaseOrderNumber = PO.PurchaseOrderNumber 
WHERE Structure.Parts.Partnumber = sp.PartNumber AND (PO.PurchaseOrderStatusCode < 4) --4 Complete 5 --Cancelled       
AND (PD.ReceiptStatusID IN (1,2) )) AS POdate,
```

AND WOdate like this (im putting this in a temp table along with the other fields)

```
(SELECT MIN(wt.CompletionDate)
FROM Structure.Parts
INNER JOIN Production.WorksOrder as wo     
ON  wo.PartID = Structure.Parts.PartID  
INNER JOIN Production.WorksOrderTransfers  wt ON wt.WorksOrderNumber = wo.WorksOrderNumber  
WHERE Structure.Parts.Partnumber = sp.PartNumber AND wt.WorksOrderStatusCode < 4      
AND (wt.BatchQuantity - ISNULL (wt.QuantityStored,0)) > 0 )
 AS WOdate,
```

My Case statement is here

```
CASE
WHEN POdate IS NULL THEN CAST(WOdate AS varchar (25))
WHEN WOdate IS NULL THEN CAST (POdate AS varchar (25))
WHEN POdate > WOdate THEN CAST (WOdate AS varchar (25)) 
WHEN POdate < WOdate THEN CAST (POdate AS varchar (25)) 
ELSE 'No Planned Stock'

END AS StockDueIn
```

Any pointers would be very much appreciated

Comment: The details needed to help you here have been eliminated by this "its not really working in with the rest of the script POdate and WOdate are populated by MIN(xxxxxx)". We need to see what you are doing. Without those details this is impossible to answer.

Comment: [Sample data and expected output](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is critical

Comment: i had posted an answer but since i agree with people who precede me i'll wait for some more details. One more point: your `CASE` statement isnt actually covering the _BOTH NULL_ scenario

Comment: Thank you for the comments noted and taken on board editing the question to add detail

Answer (score 1):

This should cover all possible scenarios

```
CASE
WHEN POdate IS NULL AND WOdate IS NULL
    THEN 'No Planned Stock'
--If desired output for BOTH EQUAL case is 'No Planned Stock'
--replace the above WHEN with below one
--WHEN ISNULL(POdate, '99990101') = ISNULL(WOdate, '99990101')
    --THEN 'No Planned Stock'
WHEN ISNULL(POdate, '99990101') > ISNULL(WOdate, '99990101')
    THEN CAST (WOdate AS varchar (25)) 
WHEN ISNULL(POdate, '99990101') < ISNULL(WOdate, '99990101')
    THEN CAST (POdate AS varchar (25)) 
END AS StockDueIn
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, Im receiving an error from the presentation layer (SSRS) "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string" using this CASE statement

Comment: The first `>` needs to `>=` to handle them both being equal. Also can use `{d'9999-01-01'}` for a static date instead of a string.

Comment: @Leighbee didnt noticed you were working on SSRS. I'm going to edit this

Comment: @B3S Sorry my head has been stuck in the stored proc for so long ive almost forgotten im writing a report.

Comment: @Brian u're right, but OP missed the desired output for _BOTH EQUAL_ case. is it _'No Planned Stock'_ maybe? If yes, just change the first `WHEN` with `WHEN ISNULL(POdate, '99990101') = ISNULL(WOdate, '99990101') THEN 'No Planned Stock'`

Comment: @B3S Im still getting the conversion error  (I changed it to..  WHEN ISNULL(POdate, '9999-01-01') = ISNULL(WOdate, '9999-01-01') THEN 'No Planned Stock'   I assume thats what you ment and added the hyphens in the date

Comment: sorry, forgot to update the rest of code in my edit (i just added the condition for 1st when case). can you check it now?

Comment: it's being a long i've not played around SSRS :D have you tried with @Brian's method? i mean, replacing the '9999-01-01' with {d'9999-01-01'}?